# App Store Connect Operation Error: Invalid entitlement for core nfc framework

Tags: ios, react-native, nfc, app-store-connect

When trying to archive my React Native application and upload to the app store I get the following error:

[image]

Here is my main app's entitlements file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
    <key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.formats</key>
    <array>
        <string>TAG</string> <!-- added TAG -->
        <string>NDEF</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.security.application-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>group.com.myapp.onesignal</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the following to your `.entitlements` file.

```xml
    <key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.formats</key>
    <array>
        <string>TAG</string> <!-- added TAG -->
        <string>NDEF</string>
    </array>
```

You then also **need to make sure you re-archive your app**. This was the reason of my issue persisting.

Comment: Doing so provides the error "The entitlements in your app bundle signature do not match the ones that are contained in the provisioning profile" for me. Did you encounter this as well?

Answer (score 4):

As at posting this answer, you cannot include NDEF in readersession in entitlements.

```
<key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.formats</key>
<array>
    <string>TAG</string>
</array>
```